# When I rotate the AVD (eclipse) the locale changue to default

Tags: android, locale, screen-orientation

... and I want to avoid that.

the app has 2 layouts (for portrait and landscape orientations) ... any idea how can I do to avoid the locale changue when the device changue his orientation?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the Locale somewhere? What are you doing that you want to avoid using the default one?

Comment: I can changue explicitly the Locale with the actionbar, and it works fine (and remains the choosen) along the nexts layouts... except if I rotate the AVD

Comment: I can copy code, but honestly I have no idea if the problem is in oncreate, in the actionbar code ...